# Running a Raku Cro app as a persistent service

Tags: raku, cro

I'd like to run a perl6/raku Cro app as a service behind a frontend webserver.

Just running `cro run` won't handle restarting after segfaults & reboots.

Previously with perl5 I've used FastCGI - however `Cro::HTTP::Server`'s `Cro::HTTP::Server.new().start()` idiom doesn't look compatible with FastCGI::Native's `while $fcgi.accept() {}` example.

The `service.p6` generated by `cro stub` does have a `SIGINT` handler, however I'm unsure whether this is sufficient to point to it in a `systemctl` service, i.e.

```
[Service]
ExecStart = /path/to/service.p6
```

How are people currently hosting Cro apps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`cro run` is intended as a development tool, not a deployment one, and so is indeed not a good choice for hosting the services.

All of the Cro services I directly take care of are containerized ([some guidance on that here](https://cro.services/docs/docker-deployment)) and then run on a hosted Kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes takes care of the automatic restarts, rolling out new versions, etc. I'm also aware of `docker-compose` being used in place of Kubernetes, which I guess works, though I believe that's also considered as primarily a development tool.

Setting it up as a `systemctl` service should also work fine, provided that's configured to always restart. However, it seems that [you'd want to handle `SIGTERM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978358/how-systemd-stop-command-actually-works/42979206#42979206) for the clean shutdown to work instead of `SIGINT` (nothing wrong with handling both).

I do also place a frontend web server in front of Cro (using Apache, though nginx would be a fine choice too), and also use that to do some caching of static content also (using [`content-control`](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-router#Setting_response_cachability) in my routes to describe the cachability).