# Using boost::process to completely detach a process

Tags: c++, boost, boost-process

I have a systemd service which runs and does its thing. Periodically I need it to upgrade itself, which requires a shutdown and a restart of the service. For question purposes the upgrade script can be as simple as:

```
echo "Stopping service..."
systemctl stop myservice
echo "Doing some stuff..."
sleep 10s
echo "Starting service..."
systemctl start myservice
```

I want to call this within the service itself, preferably using `boost::process`:

```
boost::process::child instexe{
    boost::process::search_path("bash"), 
    std::vector<std::string>{"installerscript.sh"},
    boost::process::start_dir("/installer/folder"),
    boost::process::std_out > "/some/log/file.txt"
};
instexe.detach();
```

The problem is that as soon as the script calls `systemctl stop myservice`, the installer script is killed.

Is there a way I can do what I want to do with `boost::process`? Or how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If the upgrades are at predefined period you can think of using crontab.
https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

```
00 09-17 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/installerScript.sh
```

The above entry in crontab will make the program upgrade every hour between 9 am to 5pm from Monday to Friday. There are many combinations that you can think and configure.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like this, but it really needs to be on demand. Of course, I could probably have the code in my service create a cron, but that's here nor there.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can do what I want to do with boost::process? Or how can I do it?

If you have the child process killing the parent, there's always going to be a race condition by definition.

The quick hack is to put a sleep statement at the start of the installer script, but the *correct* solution is to explicitly synchronize with the child:

1. have the installer script detect whether it's running interactively (ie, being run manually from a terminal instead of by your service)
2. if it is non-interactive (your use case), have it wait for some input in stdin
3. connect the stdin pipe when you create the child
4. detach the child and *then* write something to tell the child it's safe

Other synchronization mechanisms are available, you could use a lockfile or a signal - you just need to make sure the child doesn't do anything until after the parent has detached it.

I turns out (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42978358/212858) question, which leads to the excellent-but-unfindable `systemd.kill` manpage) that `systemd` has four different ways of stopping a unit, controlled by the `KillMode` variable in your unit configuration:

- `control-group` will send `SIGTERM` (by default, overridable with `KillSignal`) to every process in the unit's cgroup. That means both parent and child.
- `mixed` will send `SIGTERM` (or `KillSignal`) to your main process and `SIGKILL` to the child.
- `process` will kill only the main process and leave the child alone
- `none` is not recommended, it will just run your `ExecStop` procedure

You can probably just set `KillMode=process`, but note that if `SendSIGKill` or `SendSIGUP` are true, those signals will still be delivered to your child after `TimeoutStopSec`.

It seems like it might be simpler to restart your service and have a launch script that can update it at startup, or to perform the update in your `ExecStop` procedure, than to persuade `systemd` to leave the child alone until the update is complete, *without* the risk of a hung child updater hanging around forever.

Either way, your remaining problems are exclusively with `systemd` rather than with `boost.Process`.

Comment: The only synchronization I need is handled by shutting down the service. The upgrade script blocks on the `systemctl stop` call. The only problem is that it also exits out.

Comment: No, you also need synchronization to prevent the race condition that is your whole problem. _Something_ must prevent the child process from running `systemctl stop` until _after_ the parent process has detached it. That something is a form of synchronization, since it's coordinating two asynchronous processes.

Comment: Though I still can't get it to work even with the sleep and confirming the parent's code to detach it has run. I think I need to type up some sample code of a service to see if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you put the child in a different process group, as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried with `boost::process::spawn` and `boost::process::group`, and I also tried with `fork()` and `setpgid()`. I'm not 100% sure I did it right, which is why I want to find time to make a little sample program and type up another question.

Comment: My working theory now is that I'm having problems because I'm using `systemctl`. I assumed `systemctl` was doing something like `kill -SIGHUP <PID>` for the service's PID, but instead I think it's doing something like `pkill -SIGHUP <process name>`. If I ignore `SIGHUP` in the child process, the `systemctl stop` timesout, and I'm left with a single process.

Comment: Turns out there's a load of configuration around this, and that's probably where you need to focus.